# Returning value from wkbk 1 to wkbk 2 based on match result

Tags: vba, excel-2016

I've commented my code below.  I'm trying to loop through current workbook to search for cells that have a blue border (im currently testing only with Col A).

If cells have a blue border, then I want to find the matching cell on the 2nd workbook (The range will always be Column A and the 2nd workbook SHOULD always have a matching value).

When the match is found, I want to return the value from the 1st workbook (formatting included) to the 2nd workbook in the same row the match was found but in the next available column.  Most of the time it will just be Column B, but if Col B is filled then move to column C etc.)

The match function works and is returning the correct idCella.value.

and resultM is saying the correct row of the match found, but I'm not sure how to continue.

I know I need to `.offset(0,1)` the resultM but I'm missing something and I'm not sure what.

Hopefully the description helps, but if you need anymore info please let me know!

EDIT: When I say find the exact match, the value on the 2nd workbook will not have the same blue border/interior.color.  I just want to find the match of the cell.value.  That may be redundant to say, but thought I would add it.  I'm still learning :).

````
Dim testWS As Worksheet
Dim testRange As Range, rr2Dest As Range, idCella As Range
Dim alastRow2 As Long, resultM As Long

Set testWS = Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("October")                                       'set the 2nd workbook as testWS
Set testRange = testWS.Columns(1)                                                               'searching only column A on testWS (2nd workbook)
alastRow2 = Worksheets("Reruns To Pull").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                     'find last row in column A that has data on current workbook


For Each idCella In Worksheets("Reruns To Pull").Range("A1:A" & alastRow2).Cells                'for each cell in Column A on current workbook (eventually I want to loop through Column A, D, G, J.  All will be variable ranges)

        If idCella.Borders.Color = RGB(0, 0, 192) Then                                                  'On current workbook, if cells in Col A borders.color = blue then

            resultM = Application.Match(idCella.Value, testRange, 0)                                        'find exact match on Test.xlsx (2nd workbook) and store in variable resultM
                                                                                                'look up value is the first cell found on current workbook that has blue border
                                                                                                'the range I want to search is column A of Test.xlsx
            Set rr2Dest.Value = resultM                                                                        'trying to set this result to a variable so I can offset the range location by 1 column (Result from current workbook goes to Column B on Tets.xlsx workbook)

            rr2Dest.Value = idCella.Value
            rr2Dest.Interior.Color = idCella.Interior.Color                                                 'everything I want to transfer into Column B on the 2nd workbook
            rr2Dest.Borders.Color = idCella.Borders.Color
            rr2Dest.Borders.Weight = idCella.Borders.Weight
        
        End If
    
Next idCella

End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set rr2dest = testWS.Range("A" & CStr(resultM)).Offset(0, 1)`

Solved the issue.  Didn't realize the macro wasn't keeping track of what workbook it was on.  So once I specified that and used `CStr` in combination with my variable containing the match.

Just have to throw in Schutt's answer and it should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Start from rr2Dest and use `.End(xlToRight).Column` to get the next free cell and then update the value (and color, weight etc.) of this cell.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end

Comment: Sorry I know this should be so easy, but what do you mean when you say "Start from rr2Dest"?  I'm getting the error "rr2Dest.value = <Object variable or With block variable not set" and it's highlighting the ```Set rr2Dest.value = resultM```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  I still can't figure this out.